# mern stack server error api url fetch not working

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, redux

I am dispatching actions and checked and re-checked all routes and URL paths ..sound Ok but not sure why its getting error in rudux and showing 404 error in console..
I can not quite figure out what to be done about it..

```
import axios from 'axios'
export const getAllPizzas = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: 'GET_PIZZAS_REQUEST' })



 try {
    const response = await axios.get('/api/pizzas/getallpizzas')
    console.log(response)

    dispatch({ type: 'GET_PIZZAS_SUCCESS', payload: response.data })
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: 'GET_PIZZAS_FAILED', payload: error })
  }
}
```

//REDUCER

```
 export const getAllPizzasReducer = (state = { pizzas: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_PIZZAS_REQUEST':
      return { loading: true, ...state }
    case 'GET_PIZZAS_SUCCESS':
      return { laoding: false, pizzas: action.payload }
    case 'GET_PIZZAS_FAILED':
      return { error: action.payload, loading: false }
    default:
      return state
      }
    }
```

//ROUTE FILE

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Pizza = require('../models/pizzaModel')

router.get('/getallpizzas', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const pizzas = await Pizza.find({})
    res.send(pizzas)
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: error })
  }
})
```

module.exports = router
// SERVER FILE

```
const express = require('express')

const Pizza = require('./models/pizzaModel')

const app = express()
require('dotenv').config()

const db = require('./db')
app.use(express.json())

const pizzasRoute = require('./routes/pizzasRoute')
app.use('/api/pizzas/', pizzasRoute)

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Server Working nice :), Your port being ${port}`)
})

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`)
})
```

thanks

Comment: this is the error message:
     GET http://localhost:3000/api/pizzas/getallpizzas 404 xhr.js:247 (Not Found)

Comment: Unable to see the error message, is it possible to provide cmd and console error messages

Comment: xhr.js:247          GET http://localhost:3000/api/pizzas/getallpizzas 404 (Not Found)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:247
xhr @ xhr.js:49
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:51
request @ Axios.js:148
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:174
wrap @ bind.js:5
(anonymous) @ pizzaAction.js:6
(anonymous) @ index.js:16
dispatch @ VM314:1
(anonymous) @ Homescreen.js:16
commitHookEffectListMount @ react-dom.development.js:23150
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:24926
commitPassiveMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24891

Comment: commitPassiveMountEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24878
commitPassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24866
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:27039
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:26984
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26769
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533

Comment: Request URL: http://localhost:3000/api/pizzas/getallpizzas
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:3000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 162
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 12 Apr 2023 13:36:24 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Powered-By: Express

Comment: Request headers
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="104", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="104"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?1
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Android"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36

Comment: Anyone with any comments?